# DocuSign Integration Siebel IP14

Tags: integration, docusignapi, siebel

Is it feasible to integrate DocuSign with On Premise CRM applications (Siebel Remote) or it only supports integration with Cloud Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If docusign still provides a WSDL, you can still consume it in Siebel OnPremise , then create your custom WFs to have the integration running. Siebel now supports REST interfaces as well. If your siebel is remote,it cannot accept inbound webservice calls from docusign. So you will need to have one WF to submit docs for signature, and another one to query docusign for signed docs and update the links back in siebel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately we cannot use REST since it is only supported as of IP16 and we currently have IP14.

Comment: You should still be able to integrate to docusign WSDLs. I have done this docusign integration in siebel about 10 years ago using WSDLs.

Comment: Hello Ranjith,  we would like to accomplish the following firstly to push xml (Siebel data i.e order) to DocuSign, then from DocuSign put this data to the template. User will sign the template in DocuSign in offline mode (i.e Siebel iframe?) and finally the generated file will be push to Siebel. Do you see any mayor technical gap?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to integrate the two products. The first issue is to decide what you want to accomplish.

Sending out documents to be signed via DocuSign is one REST API call (after you've handled OAuth authentication of the sender).

For new eSignature applications, DocuSign highly recommends using the [eSignature REST v2.1 API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/). The DocuSign SOAP API is supported, but is in a holding pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately our current Siebel IP14 doesn't support REST API. RESTful API is only available as of IP16.